# How to initialise an array in a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want create a array like this.

```
itemList = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
```

But my code's output is

```
itemList = ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7']
```

```js
var numberList = [];
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++){
    numberList.push(i);
  }
  numberList = numberList.toString();
  this.state = {
    selectedItem : 2,
    itemList: [numberList]
  };
}
```

Comment: `numberList.push(i.toString())` inside the loop instead of `numberList = numberList.toString();` after the loop

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. Every time the constructor is called, the list will have 8 more entries added. Consider making the declaration local to the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for helping but, i'm not doing.
I edited like this. (Not working same output.)

var numberList = [];
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        for (let i = 1; i < 41; i++){
            numberList.push(i.toString())
        }
        numberList = numberList.toString();
        this.state = {
            selectedItem : 2,
            itemList: [numberList]
        
        };
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// the following will convert the whole array as a string, avoid this
// numberList = numberList.toString();

```js
var numberList = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++){
    numberList.push(i.toString());
  }
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  
  this.state = {
    selectedItem : 2,
    itemList: numberList
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, This editing is working for me.!!

Answer (score 2):

`numberList = numberList.toString();` turns your whole array into a string. Then with `itemList: [numberList]` you create a new array that contains the string as one element.

**To fix it:**

- Use `toString()` on every value in the for loop instead on the actual
  array.
- Also remove the brackets from  `itemList: [numberList]`. It
  should be `itemList: numberList` instead.

```js
var numberList = [];

for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++){
  numberList.push(i.toString());
}

console.log(numberList);
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens in your code is that you construct the array:

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

And then call `toString` on it.  Calling `toString` on an array will turn the entire array into a string, not turn each *element* of the array into the string.  So you want to call the `String` constructor on each element as you iterate over 1 -> 8.  The fixed code can be seen below.

*Note:* Not sure what the ultimate goal of this component is, but probably also want to change `selectedItem` in `this.state` from 2 -> '2', as I imagine it maps to the elements of `itemList` which are of type `String` now and not `Number`

```js
var numberList = [];
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++){
            numberList.push(String(i));
        }
        this.state = {
            selectedItem : 2,
            itemList: numberList
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it without loop using spread on `new Array` and `map` that into values:

```js
/**
 * Creates an array from start to end where start is a number smaller than end
 * It takes an optional parameter called step that defaults to 1
 * usage example:
 * range(5,9);// [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 * range(5,9,1.5);// [5, 6.5, 8]
 */
const range = (start,end,step=1)=>{
  const min = start-step
  return [...new Array(Math.floor((end-min)/step))].map(
    (val,index)=>min+(step*(index+1))
  );
};

console.log(range(5,9));
console.log(range(5,9,1.5));
```